# I cannot open up my flash drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, flash-memory

I have a flash drive that has a storage space of 8GB, a mark of  ASA MANHATTAN.

When I plug it in my computer, I get the following message:

```
This location could not be displayed.
```

Sorry, could not display all the contents of “disk”: Error when getting information for file '/media/lahcene/disk/√<Γy``FÄó.u╔╛': Input/output error

I am using a Linux OS (Ubuntu 14.10 LTS)

I can open my drive using Windows OS.

Comment: On windows, while this USB drive was mounted, right click on it and look at the properties. Does it say it is FAT32 ? Also, take a look at this helpful page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB

Comment: Is Windows running on the same machine? This looks like a hardware error. Usually the problem is with the drive but sometimes it's with the reader.

Comment: Using windows machine : Back-up your data and format your USB FAT32